# windows: is there any way to drop into command line terminal when explorer freezes completely?

Tags: windows, command-line, freeze, reboot

Lately I have had issues with Windows explorer freezing completely (i.e. mouse is stuck in busy icon and you can not click anywhere and you can not do keyboard shortcuts to pull up task-manager or ctrl-alt-delete).

In Linux, when this happens there is a simple fix you drop into command line terminal via `ctrl-alt-F2` or `ctrl-alt-F3` and then from the command line terminal you can fix the problem or at least reboot the machine gracefully.

- Fix the problem: From the command line terminal you can find fix the issue by finding the stuck process and killing the process and then go back to normal processing.
- Reboot the machine gracefully: Sometimes you can not fix the issue but you can at least tell the machine to reboot (which can in many cases save files from being corrupted like raid-1 drive from needing to be rebuilt).

#### In windows, is there any way to drop into command line terminal when explorer freezes completely?

If there is not any way to drop into the command line terminal, is there any way to recover without hard power cycle?

Comment: If frozen like you said, no way to start another App (terminal) that I know of.

Comment: Rather than looking for a work-around, fix the issue, i.e., use DISM and SFC to repair Windows, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e , and if that is not sufficient, reinstall Windows from MS ISO downloads, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO , keeping all files.